# How to pass dynamic generated arguments to function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have the function:

```
def do_something(arguments_list):
    user = User(name = argument_list['name'],
                age = argument_list['age'],
                ...
                sex = argument_list['sex'])
```

The `argument_list` (dictionary) don't always have the same keys. For example, sometimes it looks like this:

```
arguments_list = {'name': 'Zara', 'age': 7, 'sex': 'Male'}
```

but it also could be:

```
arguments_list = {'name': 'Zara'}
```

How can I dynamically pass arguments to the function (in this case constructor of User class) depends on what keys are in the dictionary?

Comment: Try **User(**arguments_list)**. This will unpack the dictionary and pass the items as arguments.

Comment: is it ok to call/instantiate `User` with only lthe `name` parameter, or do you need to set appropriate defaults that get passed into `User(...)`?

Comment: It is OK to call User only with one parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would take any number of keyword arguments and pass them to `User`:

```
def do_something(**kwargs):
    user = User(**kwargs)
```

If you know more about the arguments you could also do something like this (in this case you most likely want the `do_something` default values to be the same as the `User` default values):

```
def do_something(name=None, age=None, sex=None):
    user = User(name=name, age=age, sex=sex)
```

Let me know if something needs clarification.

---

Here you have more information about `*args` and `**kwargs`:
https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: this way `user = User(**kwargs)` I can pass the whole dictionary, but I want to assign to field names corresponding dictionary key's values. How can I do it?

Comment: The dictionary keys are used as field names. I.e. `User(**{'name': 'Paco', 'age': 23})` is equivalent to `User(name='Paco', age=23)`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly, I know how to get certain value from **kwargs, but I must assign it to certain field name (of the User class) which is the same as key from **kwargs. In other words I don't know that there exist field "name" and I have to assinge same value to this field if it was provided as a key in **kwargs.

Comment: So you are not explicitly setting the parameter `X` in `User.__init__()`, but if there is a key `X` in `kwargs` you want `User.X` to return the value of `X` in `kwargs`. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I don't have access to User class and I don't know exactly how it works. What I want to do is to prepare list of arguments in format `name = argument_list['name'],
                age = argument_list['age']`

Comment: As I understand your question `User(**kwargs)` should work, but I think I'm still missing your point. Maybe you can post a new SO question an link it from here and I'll have a look.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> def do_something(**arguments_list):
    name = arguments_list['name']


>>> do_something(name="name")
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for.